# How to calculate specific combinations of a list? (Matchmaking)

Tags: algorithm, set, racket, combinations, permutation

A friend of mine plays on a volleyball league and posed me with an interesting problem:

Each of the following letters represents a pair of players

```
; player pairs (24)
'(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x)
```

Create matches where 3 pairs are grouped to form a team (6 players on a team)

```
; teams
'((a b c) (d e f) (g h i) (j k l) (m n o) (p q r) (s t u) (v w x))
```

Combinations of teams will make up a match

```
; matches
'(((a b c) (d e f))
  ((g h i) (j k l))
  ((m n o) (p q r))
  ((s t u) (v w x)))
```

In a given night, they may play 8 to 12 matches, **but before each match, the pairs of players will randomized**. It is the facilitator's intentions to shuffle the teams as much as possible, but often times the result is far from a good distribution. `'a` will get paired too many times with `'b` etc.

In the scenario where `'(a b c)` form a team, in an ideal situation `'a` would not play on a team with `'b` or `'c` again. Likewise, `'b` would not play again with `'c`, if possible.

Simply calculating the combinations for C(24 choose 3), there are 2,024 possible teams...

```
'((a b c)
  (a b d)
  (a b e)
  ...)`
```

I was thinking I could filter out non fully unique team combinations, but this does not really lead me closer to my solution.

Consider the two following

```
'(a b c) ; team1
'(a w x) ; team2
```

These are two fully unique team combinations, but of course we couldn't put them in a match because pair `'a` cannot possibly play on two teams simultaneously. So these team combos should never be provided in a single match solution.

Another issue is, the player pairs may not be equally divisible by 6.

```
; player pairs (26)
'(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z)

; teams
'((a b c) (d e f) (g h i) (j k l) (m n o) (p q r) (s t u) (v w x))

; matches
'(((a b c) (d e f))
  ((g h i) (j k l))
  ((m n o) (p q r))
  ((s t u) (v w x)))

; sit-out this game
'(y z)
```

**Question 1:**

How can I generate a list of all possible matches composed of unique team combinations?

**Question 2:**

How can I expand the algorithm to accommodate the "sit out" players. In the event the list of player pairs is not divisible by 6, each player pair has to play/sit-out in an *equal* number of matches.

--

So I don't have much code to show for this because I keep hitting dead ends. The furthest I got was getting `X choose Y` implemented such that I had a list of all possible team combinations. I ran into trouble filtering out non-fully-unique combinations. Even if I were to succeed at that, I wouldn't know how to compose the fully unique combinations into matches.

Answers don't have to include a full implementation but pointing me in the right direction would be a lot of help. I don't have a lot of experience with this kind of computation.

Comment: For question 1, does the [`combinations`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._combinations%29%29) function do what you want? Edit: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Oh cool. I didn't known `combinations` was a built-in function. Yeah, it's a bit more complicated than just enumerating the unique combinations of 3 elements.

Answer (score 3):

You can build a solution to question 1 using the [`combinations`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._combinations%29%29) function and some extra filtering. First some data definitions:

```
;; A Player-Pair is a Symbol.
;; A Team is a (List Player-Pair Player-Pair Player-Pair).
;; A Match is a (List Team Team) where the teams are disjoint.

;; Player-Pairs : (Listof Player-Pair)
(define player-pairs '(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x))
```

So, what we want is to find the matches, but to do that we need to find a set of teams from all the combinations of 3 player-pairs, and then filter that so that it satisfies your constraint that two player-pairs should never be on a team with each other more than once.

I don't know how to do that yet, but it sounds complicated, so make it a helper function called `filter-team-combinations`.

```
;; find-teams : (Listof Player-Pair) -> (Listof Team)
(define (find-teams player-pairs)
  (filter-team-combinations (combinations player-pairs 3)))

;; filter-team-combinations : (Listof Team) -> (Listof Team)
;; Filters out teams where a player-pair would on a team with another
;; player-pair for the second time.
(define (filter-team-combinations teams) ....)
```

Hm. To know whether a given `Team` has two player-pairs that have already been on the team together, I'll need to keep track of that as well. It's probably going to be recursive, and the pairs of player-pairs that have already been together will change from one recursive call to the next. As we add to the result list, the list of pair-pairs will grow larger. So we need to add it as an argument, which starts out as an empty list.

```
;; find-teams : (Listof Player-Pair) -> (Listof Team)
(define (find-teams player-pairs)
  (filter-team-combinations (combinations player-pairs 3) (list)))

;; A Pair-Pair is a (List Player-Pair Player-Pair)

;; filter-team-combinations : (Listof Team) (Listof Pair-Pair) -> (Listof Team)
;; Filters out teams where a player-pair would on a team with another
;; player-pair for the second time.
;; pair-pairs is an accumulator that stores the pair-pairs that we've
;; seen so far.
(define (filter-team-combinations teams pair-pairs) ....)
```

The `filter-team-combinations` function processes a list of teams, and a list can be either empty or the first team consed onto the rest of the teams:

```
(define (filter-team-combinations teams pair-pairs)
  (cond [(empty? teams) ....]
        [else .... (first teams) .... (rest teams) ....]))
```

For the base case, if there are no teams to filter, we return the empty list. For the recursive case, well, it will have to look at the pairs of player-pairs that the first team contains, check whether those conflict with the existing `pair-pairs`, and branch on that:

```
(define (filter-team-combinations teams pair-pairs)
  (cond [(empty? teams) (list)]
        [else
         (define new-pair-pairs (combinations (first teams) 2))
         (cond [(pair-pairs-conflict? new-pair-pairs pair-pairs)
                .... (first teams) .... (rest teams) ....]
               [else
                .... (first teams) .... (rest teams) ....])]))

;; pair-pairs-conflict? : (Listof Pair-Pair) (Listof Pair-Pair) -> Boolean
(define (pair-pairs-conflict? as bs) ....)
```

So, pretending that `pair-pairs-conflict?` does the right thing, we'll fill in the `....`s to finish `filter-team-combinations`. In the case where they conflict, we should drop the first team and recur on the rest. In the case where they don't conflict, we should cons the first team onto something.

```
(define (filter-team-combinations teams pair-pairs)
  (cond [(empty? teams) (list)]
        [else
         (define new-pair-pairs (combinations (first teams) 2))
         (cond [(pair-pairs-conflict? new-pair-pairs pair-pairs)
                ;; This team has a pair-pair that a previous team already had,
                ;; so don't include this team in the result; recur on the rest.
                (filter-team-combinations (rest teams) pair-pairs)]
               [else
                ;; Cons this team onto something.
                (cons (first teams)
                      ....)])]))
```

For the last `....`, we need to recur on the rest, but we also need to make sure that the recursive call knows that the player-pairs in the first team shouldn't be on the same team again. To do that we can append them onto the `pair-pairs` argument.

```
;; filter-team-combinations : (Listof Team) (Listof Pair-Pair) -> (Listof Team)
;; Filters out teams where a player-pair would on a team with another
;; player-pair for the second time.
;; pair-pairs is an accumulator that stores the pair-pairs that we've
;; seen so far.
(define (filter-team-combinations teams pair-pairs)
  (cond [(empty? teams) (list)]
        [else
         (define new-pair-pairs (combinations (first teams) 2))
         (cond [(pair-pairs-conflict? new-pair-pairs pair-pairs)
                ;; This team has a pair-pair that a previous team already had,
                ;; so don't include this team in the result; recur on the rest.
                (filter-team-combinations (rest teams) pair-pairs)]
               [else
                ;; Add this team and add the new pair-pairs.
                (cons (first teams)
                      (filter-team-combinations (rest teams)
                                                (append new-pair-pairs pair-pairs)))])]))
```

So now we need to implement the `pair-pairs-conflict?` predicate.

```
;; pair-pairs-conflict? : (Listof Pair-Pair) (Listof Pair-Pair) -> Boolean
;; A team must be made up of sets of player-pairs that haven't been on the
;; same team yet. This function takes two lists of player-pair pairs.
;; Each pair-pair in the first list has two player-pairs that would now be
;; on the same team.
;; Each pair-pair in the second list has two player-pairs that have been
;; on the same team already.
;; This function returns true iff any player-pair would be on the same
;; team with anyone they have already been on the same team with.
(define (pair-pairs-conflict? as bs) ....)
```

It needs to take each pair-pair in the `as` and check whether it's in `bs`, and it conflicts if any `a` is in `bs`. One way to do that is with an `ormap`, and another way to do that is with `for/or`.

```
(define (pair-pairs-conflict? as bs)
  (for/or ([a (in-list as)])
    (member a bs)))
```

There's one problem with this though. The pair-pair `(list 'a 'b)` should be considered the same as the pair-pair `(list 'b 'a)`. So we need a `member` function that doesn't care about this ordering thing. Luckily, `member` can take a third argument for it to use as an equality predicate.

```
(define (pair-pairs-conflict? as bs)
  (for/or ([a (in-list as)])
    (member a bs pair-pair=?)))

;; pair-pair=? : Pair-Pair Pair-Pair -> Boolean
(define (pair-pair=? a b)
  (match-define (list a1 a2) a)
  (match-define (list b1 b2) b)
  (or (and (equal? a1 b1) (equal? a2 b2))
      (and (equal? a1 b2) (equal? a2 b1))))
```

Now we have everything we need to find all the valid sets of teams.

```
(define teams (find-teams player-pairs))
```

To find matches, we need combinations of two teams, but we need to filter them to make sure that the teams are disjoint, so that a player-pair never plays against itself.

```
;; find-matches : (Listof Team) -> (Listof Match)
(define (find-matches teams)
  (filter match-has-disjoint-teams? (combinations teams 2)))

;; match-has-disjoint-teams? : Match -> Boolean
(define (match-has-disjoint-teams? match)
  (teams-disjoint? (first match) (second match)))

;; teams-disjoint? : Team Team -> Boolean
(define (teams-disjoint? team-1 team-2) ....)
```

To implement `teams-disjoint?`, we need to match every player-pair in `team-1` against every player-pair in `team-2` and make sure none of those are equal to each other. One way to do that would be with `cartesian-product` and `andmap`, but another way would be to use `for*/and`.

```
;; teams-disjoint? : Team Team -> Boolean
(define (teams-disjoint? team-1 team-2)
  (for*/and ([p1 (in-list team-1)]
             [p2 (in-list team-2)])
    (not (equal? p1 p2))))
```

Using `find-matches`:

```
> (find-matches (list (list 'a 'b) (list 'b 'c) (list 'c 'd) (list 'd 'a)))
(list (list (list 'a 'b) (list 'c 'd))
      (list (list 'b 'c) (list 'd 'a)))
> (find-matches (list (list 'a 'b 'c)
                      (list 'c 'd 'e)
                      (list 'e 'f 'g)
                      (list 'g 'h 'i)))
(list (list (list 'a 'b 'c) (list 'e 'f 'g))
      (list (list 'a 'b 'c) (list 'g 'h 'i))
      (list (list 'c 'd 'e) (list 'g 'h 'i)))
```

My attempted solution to question 1 was to compose `find-matches` with `find-teams`:

```
(find-matches (find-teams player-pairs))
```

With 24 different player-pairs, this produces 1,624 different match-ups.

Although, while two player-pairs would never be together on different teams, this includes match-ups where are together with the *same* team that they have been in in a different match-up.

That's probably not what you wanted. It might help you get there though, so I'll post it anyway.

Comment: Alex, thank you for the thorough exposition. The insight on the thought process to break the problem down into smaller parts is exactly what I was looking for. `find-matches` doesn't provide the final output I'm looking for, but it's a huge step in the direction I'm trying to go. I should be able to continue to work in a way you have demonstrated to reach the goal.